# Use Robolectric to test starting of a service with intent extras?

Tags: android, testing, android-intent, robolectric

Can I use Robolectric to test that an Activity starts a Service with a specific Bundle passed with the Intent? **Answer:** Yes!

I want to write a Robolectric-based test that tests that my `MainActivity` starts `MyService` with a specific number passed in intent extras:

in "MainActivity.java" I have the method

```
public void startMyService() {
  Intent i = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
  Bundle intentExtras = new Bundle();
  // TODO: Put magic number in the bundle
  i.putExtras(intentExtras);
  startService(i);
}
```

and this is my test case "MainActivityTest.java":

```
import ...

@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class)
public class MainActivityTest extends TestCase {
  @Override
  protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
  }

  @Override
  protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
    super.tearDown();
  }

  @Test
  public void testShallPassMagicNumberToMyService() {
    MainActivity activityUnderTest = Robolectric.setupActivity(MainActivity.class);
    activityUnderTest.startMyService();

    Intent receivedIntent = shadowOf(activityUnderTest).getNextStartedService();

    assertNotNull("No intents received by test case!", receivedIntent);

    Bundle intentExtras = receivedIntent.getExtras();
    assertNotNull("No intent extras!", intentExtras);

    long receivedMagicNumber = intentExtras.
            getLong(MyService.INTENT_ARGUMENT_MAGIC_NUMBER);

    assertFalse("Magic number is not included with the intent extras!",
            (receivedMagicNumber == 0L));  // Zero is default if no 'long' was put in the extras
  }
}
```

So, my question is:
**Can I use Robolectric for this purpose?**

**I think I figured this out, see answer below...**

The test case does not work because it reports "No intent extras!". Using the debugger I've noticed that Intent.putExtras() has no effect in the Robolectric environment. The `i.mExtras` (`Intent.mExtras`) property is correctly set to a Bundle reference when I run the app on my device. When I run the test case it is `null`. I suppose that this hints that the answer to my question is "no", so should I give up on this test case or is there any way to accomplish this test?

**Edit:** Corrected the example `startMyActivity()` method to reflect what I actually had a problem with: It seems the `Intent.mExtras` property does not get populated unless there are some contents in the `Bundle`(?). This differs from the live Android environment which is what I analyzed with the debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not entirely accurate in how I presented my example code! I've updated the example to show the code I was having trouble with.

Turns out there's a difference in how an Intent is managed in the Robolectric environment compared to the real Android environment. With Robolectric `Intent.mExtras` does not get populated by `Intent.putExtras()` unless there's actually some content in the `Bundle` added to the `Intent` as extras.

Comment: Interesting. I think by default Robolectric is using API16 AOSP. What is Android version that are you debugging? Can you add `@Config{emulateSdk=<android version>} to your test? I just wonder if it is specific of Android version or Robolectric

Comment: Hi Eugen, thank you for this hint. I'm using `targetSdkVersion 19` for the app. I tried `emulateSdk = {16,18,21}` for the test but the result is always the same: If I do `Intent.putExtras()` with a fresh `Bundle` that I haven't added any data to, then `Intent.mExtras` remains `null` in the Robolectric environment. What does "AOSP" stand for?

Comment: ...add `19` to the set of (Robolectric)emulated SDKs.

Comment: AOSP is Android Open Source Project

Comment: Let me check Robolectric sources :)

Comment: I'd love to hear if you find anything interesting Eugen, and thank you for your input. I'm going to mark this question as "answered" for now.

Comment: I checked code. It should work actually correctly. When you call `putExtras(Bundle)` it should copied and propagated. So looks like it is bug in Robolectric. I will try to reproduce issue and submit bug to Robolectric. What version of Robolectric do you use?